# Processing each row before passing it to a doT template

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I've been looking into the [doT javascript templating engine](http://olado.github.com/doT/), but my data's in an odd format. Is there some built-in way to process each row before it goes to the template? I'd rather build individual row objects on the fly before they render than clone-and-modify the whole data array beforehand, which of course would work. I could also dig into the code and fork it myself, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a standard feature.

Is there some better place to ask questions about doT?

**EDIT:** To explain more fully what I'm trying to do, this is what the data looks like (a ColdFusion query serialized to JSON):

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["fname", "lname"],
    "DATA":
    [
            ["John", "Smith"],
            ["Jean", "Summers"],
            ["Jane", "Sturgess"]
    ]
}
```

So an awkward answer is just this:

```
{{~it.DATA :v:i}}
<div>{{=v[it.COLUMNS.indexOf('fname')]}} {{=v[it.COLUMNS.indexOf('lname')]}} ({{=i}}</div>
{{~}}
```

You could also hard code the column indexes, but the template is much less readable.

But I'd rather that the template was less verbose and more intuitive. This is a step in that direction, but still funky:

```
{{
var cols = {};
for(var i=0, n=it.COLUMNS.length; i<n; i++) {
    cols[it.COLUMNS[i]] = i;
}
{ }}
{{ } }}

{{~it.DATA :v:i}}
<div>{{=v[cols.fname]}} {{=v[cols.lname]}} ({{=i}})</div>
{{~}}
```

And another step, hand coded, but the template is somewhat prettier:

```
{{##def.fname:{{=v[0]}}#}}
{{##def.lname:{{=v[1]}}#}}

{{~it.DATA :v:i}}
<div>
{{#def.fname}} {{#def.lname}} ({{=i}})
</div>
{{~}}
```

You could generate those partials, but I very much doubt you could make that step part of the template itself.

Probably a better solution would be to skip the snippets, have external code read the column definitions out of the data, read the template, replace colName in these '{{=colName}}' with indexes looked up in the column definitions, then compile and run the result.

If anyone has any further thoughts on this, I'd love to hear them.